# I want to get my listview scroll to the selected item and change the selected item design

Tags: c#, listview, webforms

I want to get my listview to scroll to the user selected index and change its appearance. I tired to get this in many ways but nothing worked for me.

When I select any item from listview I am able to get the data and index of selected item but the SelectedTemplate apply on previous Index. Don't know how ?

for eg: By Default I **selected index "0"**, so when I **select index "3"** the **SelectedTemplate applies on index "0"** and when I **select index "5"** the **SelectedTemplate applies on index "3"**.

Codes are below, hope to get some help from Stack Overflow.

**WebForm**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">

        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="VDOContainer raw">
                <div class="vdoname" id="area" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="VDOName" runat="server" CssClass="vdofonthead" Text="Video Name"></asp:Label>
                </div>

                <div class="boxleft col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                    <asp:Literal ID="lblvedio" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    <ul class="raw like-section">
                        <li class="col-md-6 like-btn">
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Like" runat="server" Text="Like" CssClass="btn btn-outline btn-lg"></asp:Button>
                            <div class="btn btn-lg" style="cursor:default;">
                                <img class="vlike" src="img/like.png" alt="like image" />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblLike" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn btn-lg" style="cursor:default;">
                                <img class="vlike" src="img/like.png" alt="like image" />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblView" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                Views
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="vdoname" id="Div1" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="VDODesc" runat="server" CssClass="vdofonthead" Text="Video Description"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="boxright col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="listviedo"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="listviedo_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanging="listviedo_SelectedIndexChanging"
                        SelectedIndex="0" FullRowSelect="true" 
                        DataKeyNames="VID" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="selected_panel" >
                                <div class="vdofont">
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkbtn" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("VID") %>'>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VideoName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("VID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <SelectedItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="selected_panel" CssClass="boxright_active" BackColor="SkyBlue"> 
                                <div class="vdofont boxright_active">
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkbtn" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("VID") %>'>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VideoName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("VID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </SelectedItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="listviedo" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="listviedo" EventName="SelectedIndexChanging" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="listviedo" EventName="ItemCommand" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C# Behind**

```
protected void listviedo_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Literal lblvedio = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("lblvedio");
        Label lblname = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblname");
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            Database.Tbl obj = DB.Tbl.Single(p => p.VID == ID);
            if (obj.IsUrl == false)
            {
                string Link = "<iframe></iframe>";
            }
            else
            {
                string Link = "<iframe></iframe>";
            }
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "Resume")
        {
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            Database.Tbl objcar = DB.Tbl.Single(p => p.VID == ID); 
        }
    }
    protected void listviedo_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblid = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblid");
        LinkButton linkresuume = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("linkresuume");
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(lblid.Text);
        Database.Tbl objcar = DB.Tbl.Single(p => p.VID == ID);            
    }
    protected void listviedo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["USER"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login");
        }
        else
        {
                            if (listviedo.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                int id1 = Convert.ToInt32(listviedo.SelectedValue.ToString());
                lblvedio.Text = getvalue(id1);
                VDOName.Text = getName(id1);
                VDODesc.Text = getDesc(id1);
                lblView.Text = getView(id1).ToString();
                lblLike.Text = getLike(id1).ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void listviedo_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
    { 
        this.listviedo.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex; 
    }
```

**CSS**

```
.boxright {
            float: left;
            height: 890px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.12);
        }

        .boxright div:hover {
            transform: scale(1.01);
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px #777;
            border-radius:5px;
        }

        .boxright_active {
            transform: scale(1.01);
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 0px #777;
            border-radius:5px;
        }

        .boxright div:active {
            transform: scale(1.01);
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 0px #777;
            border-radius:5px;
        }

        .boxleft {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 15px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```

Comment: if you are using jQuery on your project you can use scrollTop() function. Check documentation here https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: I dont have any idea how to use jQuery @stanke